# Electronic component identification and sourcing

Tags: surface-mount

I'm trying to repair a electronic component but don't know what it is called and where I'd get a couple of them.  The 2 to the right have the number on them.  425 BGT is what it looks to be. [image] Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.  Perry

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a **SMCJ78CA Bidirectional Transient Suppression Diode**, if that makes any sense for your board.  These parts are available from all the big distributors, approx £0.50/unit at 1-off.

Board shows D1, D2, D3 but no apparent polarity markings.

Datasheets below show same part numbers for right-looking package, labelled **BGT**, which are diodes which don't need polarity markings.  My guess is that "425" is the date code.

- https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smcj_datasheet.pdf.pdf
- https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds19003.pdf

Eg Littelfuse datasheet shows part numbers and marking for the unidirectional and bidirectional 78V diodes:
[image]

Don't follow my guess blindly!

Comment: Thank you so much.  I read the data sheet and this makes sense for the application.  It's a solar panel charge controller that received a over current that killed the diode.  The Diodes Incorporated page has a large list of SMCJ numbers.  How does one determine what I have so a replacement is correct?  I appreciate your suggesting it might be SMCJ78CA but how can I be sure.  The BGT designation and 425 are not all that clear.  This is all new to me.  Thanks.

Comment: Just saw the BGT in the 2nd to right column.   Makes sense now.  I'll order some and give it a go and will be sure to let you know. Thanks

Comment: I don't think the manufacturers make it easy at all, so I added an image, perhaps it's helpful for someone tracking a similar part down.  I don't recognise the logo in your photo, but sleuthing suggests it's an old Rectron logo; they do make this kind of diode, but they use different marking.  Other part with this logo: https://www.recycledgoods.com/rectron-mb256-bridge-rectifier-diode-600v-25a-glass-passivated-new-stock/

Comment: Thanks.  I orded up some of the SMCJ78CA ones.  Look forward to putting one in to see if the charge controller works.  Bless you all for your  help!!!

Answer (score 2):

It’s a Schottky barrier diode.

From the PCB you can see the markings D1 D2 etc.

This is where the diodes need to be soldered onto the board.

Here’s a similar diode:

[image]

(Image source: https://ly.rsdelivers.com/product/diodeszetex/b360a-13-f/diodes-inc-60v-3a-schottky-diode-2-pin-do-214ac/9228121)